# How to pass Class Type of some Inner class from Java source to Scala?

Tags: java, scala

I have some java code which defines two classes as follows

```java
public class Foo{
      /*Some code here*/

      private final Bar b = new Bar(); //Object of inner class.

      final class Bar{

      /*Some code here*/
      }

      @Override
      public Class<? extends SomeClass> getSerializedClass(){
        return Bar.class;
      }

    }
```

Now I want pass the type of inner class **Bar** to some other code in Scala.

```scala
trait Trait1 {

  def func1[B](path: String, overwrite:Boolean= false, value:Int ) = {

    val converter = new OutputConverter[A, Bar, B] (K,V)
    Sink[A, B](path, converter, overwrite)


}

case class Sink[K, B](path: String,
                      outputConverter: OutputConverter[A, Bar, B],
                      overwrite: Boolean = false) extends DataSink[A, Bar, B] with SinkSource {
   /**Some code here*/

}
```

The difficulty is that I cannot change the Java code.
Can anyone please tell me a method to it?

Comment: What do you mean by ` I want pass the Class type of inner class Bar to some other code in Scala.`? I am sorry I dont understand the question

Comment: `Bar` is declared protected in the Java code.  Passing it outside to another class, in Java or some other language is cause for concern.  You may be best served to copy what you need out of Bar and pass that.

Comment: @Jatin : I want to pass type information of inner class to one generic method in Scala code. I apologize if I was not clear enough earliar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use it as a type (like `Foo.Bar` in Java): `Foo#Bar` (e.g. `OutputConverter[A, Foo#Bar, B]`).

If you want a `Class[_]` object (like `Foo.Bar.class` in Java): `classOf[Foo#Bar]`.

EDIT: I didn't notice that `Bar` isn't public. If your Scala code is in the same package as Java code, you should be able to access it in the above ways; if it isn't, you can't access `Bar` (except by reflection) and shouldn't be able too.

See http://www.iulidragos.org/?p=166 for some more details.

Comment: Don't you think he should make the `Bar` class `static` for this to work? I'm curious because I'm not sure.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce No, he shouldn't.

Comment: Cannot change Java code as that code is part of a library.

Comment: @PrashantBhardwaj Then the library author is specifically disallowing you access to `Bar` by not making it public. As the answer says, you can bypass it by e.g. putting your code into the same package, but this isn't a good idea.